in/to that/which degree
(1) It is as cold as ice.
(2) It is in that degree cold in which degree ice is cold.
In a grammar book for Japanese high school students, the author paraphrases (1) as (2).
Are the two in's in (2) correct? I would use to instead.
(3) It is to that degree cold to which degree ice is cold.

(2) is a deliberately "wooden" paraphrase, intended as explanation of as...as  not as an idiomatic replacement for as...as.. Both instances of "in" are grammatical and necessary. The second "in" could not be omitted.  to is a viable alternative to in.

@TimR. Thank you. Does the in indicate a range?

No, in there does not indicate "range". Compare "I would like the jacket to be in a darker color."  Or "He did not get any sleep and is in a bad mood." or "The piece is in G major".  The preposition has many meanings but there it introduces a state or condition which is an attribute of the thing being spoken of.

The attribute of coldness is its degree. How cold is it? Coldness has no other attributes.

Usually a paraphrase restates complicated language in simpler language!

As I see it, the textbook's paraphrased sentence isn't valid. (It also seems like it doesn't meet its goal of explaining, since it's more complicated and confusing than the original!) But its biggest problem isn't about "in" or "to." It's that the word "degree" shouldn't happen the second time.
Let's make some simpler sentences using "in which."

This is the cupboard in which glasses are stored. This is equivalent to "Glasses are stored in this cupboard." Using "in which" this way lets us sort of flip the sentence order: In "Glasses are stored in this cupboard," "glasses" is the subject; in the "in which" sentence, the cupboard is the subject. Both sentences have the same meaning, but we might choose this order if we wanted to put more importance on the cupboard, for instance if we were comparing one cupboard to another. (Other words can do the same thing, like "This is the house that Jack built.")
Let's make a sentence similar to the pattern of the original. The pitcher is in the cupboard in which glasses are stored. Note, I said "cupboard" only once. This sentence, from the words "the cupboard" on, are the same as the previous example and works the same way. It would be wrong to say "The pitcher is in the cupboard in which cupboard glasses are stored," because that would be equivalent to something like "glasses are stored in the cupboard the cupboard."

This is the biggest problem with the textbook's sentence. When it says "in that degree cold in which degree," it's just like that extra "cupboard."
Now, setting aside that problem, we can talk about "in that degree" vs "to that degree." Both prepositions are used with "degree." I find it a little hard to say exactly which should have been used with this sentence because the sentence itself is so un-idiomatic (even without the extra "degree"). I think, after talking about the cupboards, that I take back what I said in a comment; it doesn't have to be "in that degree to which"; I think instead it should use either "to" or "in" both times. But anyway, let's look at how these prepositions are used:

"...in the ___ degree" is an idiomatic pattern. By far, the most common word in that blank is "highest." "He is a gentleman in the highest degree." This figure of speech isn't all that common and is a bit stilted; it might be appropriate when giving a fancy speech, but not in everyday use.
"...to the ___ degree" is also standard. In fact, the blank is often replaced by "Nth." I'm guessing, like the mathematical use of N, this use of "to" mirrors the way we talk about exponents, "to the nth power."

Now, regardless, the sentence fails its mission because it was meant to explain and has only confused (me as well as you!). Any figure of speech about "degree" is not normally used in this complicated parallel comparison way. Let's see if we can make any simpler, clearer paraphrases for "It is as cold as ice." —First of all, note that the textbook explains this figure of speech very literally, but it is almost never meant literally. If I say "Wow, your feet are as cold as ice!", I don't mean that they are truly 0 degrees centigrade. If they are you are in big medical trouble. It's almost always hyperbole. This kind of "comparison hyperbole" is common. Pick an adjective, and compare your thing to an extreme example of that adjective. As hot as the sun, as deep as the ocean, as white as snow. So the best paraphrase is simply "It's very cold."
But just to explain the mechanisms of "It's as cold as ice," and its literal meaning, let's see if we can do better. We're trying to explain the figure of speech "as X as Y," as in "He's as tall as Jim." We might just say,

He is as tall as Jim is tall. That might help someone understand. But if they don't understand the word "as," we could go farther:
He is the same amount tall that Jim is tall. This ought to be easy to understand. It's a little bit un-idiomatic, though, because you can't have "an amount of tall-ness." That's why the textbook turned to "degree":
He is the tall to the same degree that Jim is tall. Or "in the same degree" would be fine too. But this version, using "same," seems easier to understand and closer to idiomatic usage than the textbook's pattern.


I'm a native speaker from the western U.S.
I would never use your example (2). In fact, I had to look at it a bit to make sure I understood it. However, if we're going to be strict according to grammar and the point is to teach you the equivalence of a phrase and not its use... yes, (1) and (2) are equivalent.
In that degree is a very formal identification of a characteristic: degree. Without the word "cold" the phrase wouldn't make sense because "degree" as a characteristic is used in multiple ways. For example, I could use the same phrase like this:

It is in that degree acute in which degree the angles of an isosceles triangle are acute.

In this case "degree" refers to the degrees of angular measurement. The phrase, which identifies a characteristic, is used more commonly in these ways:

In that case I don't want to go to the theater.
In that way I could save fifteen minutes of time.

Compare this to "to the degree," which expresses a comparison or measurement.

He is arrogant to the degree of irritation.
He is obtuse to the point of frustration.

Because "to the degree" is not identifying a characteristic, but is expressing a comparison, no, (3) is not correct.
For the record, the way I'd say (2) is to use the comparison form: "It is cold to the degree of ice." But if I told you it was the right way to say it, I'd be doing your textbook a disservice. Your book is trying to make a point and the lesson must not give way to spoken English.

Thanks for answering! I'd like to offer friendly disagreements with a few points. 1) I wouldn't say the textbook's paraphrase is "equivalent," because I don't think it's valid, while the original was. 2) Thanks for bringing up "to the degree." I think a valid (while still confusing) version would be "It is in that degree cold to which ice is cold." I'll write my own answer explaining how that works.

@AndyBonner Thank you. I'm looking forward to your explanation.
